# comparing null BigDecimal from Java BigDecimal

Tags: java, scala, implicit

I have the following code:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_45).

scala> val z: BigDecimal = null
z: BigDecimal = null

scala> z == null
res0: Boolean = true
```

Which looks fine. however...

```
scala> import java.math.{BigDecimal => JBigDecimal}
import java.math.{BigDecimal=>JBigDecimal}

scala> val x: JBigDecimal = null
x: java.math.BigDecimal = null
```

In the REPL, assigning will throw NPE:

```
scala> val y: BigDecimal = x
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at scala.math.BigDecimal.toString(BigDecimal.scala:452)
    at scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$.scala$runtime$ScalaRunTime$$inner$1(ScalaRunTime.scala:324)
    at scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$.stringOf(ScalaRunTime.scala:329)
    at scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$.replStringOf(ScalaRunTime.scala:337)
    at .<init>(<console>:10)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

Using a Lazy variable will present the issue I'm mainly concerned about.

```
scala> lazy val y: BigDecimal = x
y: BigDecimal = <lazy>

scala> y == null
res1: Boolean = false
```

Any suggestions? Is this last comparison a bug? 
I've considered wrapping both elements in Options, but i would first like to understand why is this happening.

Furthermore, comparing those two BigDecimals, also causes another (possibly different, although related) exception

```
scala> z == y
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at scala.math.BigDecimal.toLongExact(BigDecimal.scala:411)
    at scala.math.BigDecimal$$anonfun$isValidLong$1.apply$mcV$sp(BigDecimal.scala:196)
    at scala.math.BigDecimal.noArithmeticException(BigDecimal.scala:211)
    at scala.math.BigDecimal.isValidLong(BigDecimal.scala:196)
    at scala.math.BigDecimal.equals(BigDecimal.scala:190)
    at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.equalsNumNum(BoxesRunTime.java:168)
```

I used to get this more frequently interesting that was using assert

A reworked, more concrete example:

```
  test("Both cases should be true") {
    val x: JBigDecimal = null
    val y: JBigDecimal = null
    x should be (null)
    y should be (null)
    x == y should be (true)

    val i :BigDecimal = x
    val j :BigDecimal = y

    i == j should be (true)
  }
```

However, it fails when comparing i == j

Furthermore, even if using options, by implicitly converting JBigDecimal to BigDecimal, i still get the BigDecimal(null) instance.

I tested this bug report, and when i ran [BigDecimalBug](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6567), it failed the assertion.

So far, the only approach that I have reproduced to work OK is the following:

```
it("test implicit conversions from null Java BigDecimal to Option[BigDecimal]"){
  val x: JBigDecimal = null
  val y: JBigDecimal = null
  x should be (null)
  y should be (null)
  x == y should be (true)

  val i :BigDecimal = x
  val j :BigDecimal = y

  implicit def convertJBigDecimalOption(javaBigDecimal: JBigDecimal): Option[BigDecimal] =
    Option(javaBigDecimal) map { x => BigDecimal(x.toString) }

  val p :Option[BigDecimal] = x
  val q :Option[BigDecimal] = y

  p should be('empty)
  q should be('empty)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `NullPointerException` is occurring because the REPL calls `toString()` after the val assignment, which throws the exception. This is why it's not throwing the exception using lazy evaluation, since it doesn't call `toString()` then.

`scala.math.BigDecimal` is a class that holds a `java.math.BigDecimal`, but an instance of `scala.math.BigDecimal` holding a null value isn't a null reference itself. In your example `(y.bigDecimal == null)` will evaluate to true.

In any case, `Option` was created for a reason, and it's a much better idea to use it instead of assigning and checking nulls.

Edit:

Doing something like this:

```
val x : java.math.BigDecimal = null
BigDecimal(x) == BigDecimal(x)
```

.. Will throw a `NullPointerException` because `BigDecimal` will inevitably call this:

```
def compare (that: BigDecimal): Int = this.bigDecimal compareTo that.bigDecimal
```

.. Which compares the wrapped `java.math.BigDecimal`s, and `compareTo` throws the exception when it finds the null.

Comment: I understand all of that, but doesn't address the point that we now have created a BigDecimal(null) which will fail at any moment once evaluated, instead of assigning null.

Comment: It doesn't fail when it's evaluated, it fails when `toString` is called upon it. Why should `BigDecimal(null) == null`? I don't know of  another class that works that way. Whether you think it's a bug or not, you'd be hard pressed to get behavior like that in the scala language.

Comment: see z == null. Looking into the BoxesRuntime:168, we find:

         if ((yn instanceof ScalaNumber) && !(xn instanceof ScalaNumber))
                return yn.equals(xn);

Comment: I don't understand what you're getting at. `val Z:BigDecimal = null` is not the same as `BigDecimal(null)`.

Comment: typo, i meant the last example. z == y

Comment: I've added to my answer.